# What is :source in the Token module?

Tags: nodes, tokens

I look at the [List of tokens](https://www.drupal.org/node/390482) and I see a lot of tokens with the same name and description, but some `node` have `:source` appended to it. Some of these, such as `[node:title]`, I can understand, since `title` is a field of the node. But what is `[node:source:title]`, or `[node:source:source:title]`? There's even an `[node:source:source:source:source]`, which has the description 'The source node for this current node's translation set.'

What is :source in the Token module?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`:source` you can understand as parent of that node when you get in touch with [drupal translation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21translation%21translation.module/7) you can easily understand what hierarchy this `:source` is referring to.

as per above link:

Translations are managed in sets of posts, which represent the same information in different languages. Only content types for which the administrator has explicitly enabled translations could have translations associated. **Translations are managed in sets with exactly one source post per set. The source post is used to translate to different languages**, so if the source post is significantly updated, the editor can decide to mark all translations outdated.

so `:source` here is referring to the parent node from which it gets translated (if there are translation enabled if not then you need not to worry about `:source`)

Comment: Beat me to it :)

Comment: Very clear, thank you! I'm not familiar with translation, so it'd go a long way if you could also comment on why there are things like `[node:source:source:source:source]`. Thanks again!

Comment: I have mentioned same in answer as well this refer to hierarchy :source means parent, :source:source means grand parent and so on...